# Squarespace: form submission failure: After successfully processing form data with JavaScript, the form doesn't submit to Mailchimp

Tags: forms, mailchimp, squarespace, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a form in a Squarespace form block. I successfully intercept the form before submission (using a `form.submit()`listener) and successfully read and process the data. I only read the form data (`Array.from($('select'))`). I don't interfere with the form structure or the submission process other than to intercept it before submission. `e.preventDefault()` is not set.

The JavaScript successfully executes. It submits table update data to an Amazon Web Services table. AWS sends logs to the console acknowledging success. I let the JavaScript terminate upon success. I have tried a `form.submit()` call at the end, but it has no effect.

There are no error messages.

**The really curious, anomalous behavior is** that I've tested it and found that of the five tests, two (the first and third) succeeded in updating my Mailchimp list while three did not. For those three, I received a Squarespace email notice of form submission failure. It gives no error message other than to say the submission to MailChimp failed.

However, when I made the connection to an email address, the submission succeeded every time. I got an email notice of the submission. It's just when the form storage is MailChimp that the submission fails (sometimes).

I disconnected the MailChimp list from the form in the Squarespace form storage dialog. I removed Squarespace from the list of approved applications on Mailchimp I reconnected storage to my Mailchimp list and tested it again. The submission failed.

You can find the form on [this page](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-register-2019/). All the JavaScript can be found on [this page](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-javascript/). I've also put it in the snippet below. It doesn't have a live connection to AWS because I would have to put my AWS 'secret' access key in the script and I'm reluctant to do that.

If someone can give me guidance as to why this occurs and how to fix it, I'd sure be grateful. In fact, I'm grateful that you've read this far whether or not you can help. Thanks.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = Array.from($('select'))
    .map((select, i) => ({
      'index': i,
      'room': select.value
    }))
    .filter(select => select.room !== 'unsure' && select.room !== 'not attend');
  if( !a || a.length == 0 ) {console.log('a is null or undefined, or a.length == 0');}
    else {
     if(a[0].room == 'attend') {a[0].room = 'chapel';}  
     alert(JSON.stringify(a));
//   updateTable(a);
   }  //  end else
}); //  end def anonymous fn & submit

function updateTable(classes) {
  var timeslots = ['0830', '0900', '1030']
  var params = {};
  var ts = '';
  var rm = '';
  var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  var err = null;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    ts = timeslots[classes[i].index];
    rm = classes[i].room;
    console.log('ts, rm : ', ts, rm);
    params = {
                  'TableName': 'FHCRoomCounts',
                  'Key': {
                            'room': {
                                      'S' : rm
                                    },
                            'timeSlot': {
                                           'S': ts
                                        }
                         },
                  'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                                                '#registrants': 'registrants'
                                              },
                  'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
                                                 ':n': { 'N': '1'} 
                                               
                                               },
                  'UpdateExpression': 'ADD #registrants :n',
                  'ReturnValues': 'ALL_NEW'
             };  // end params
             
               console.log('log params for i == ' + i);
               console.log(params);
               console.log('Executing dynamoDB updateItem on iteration i = ' + i);
                                        
    dynamoDB.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
                      console.log('Unable to update registrant: ' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
            } else {
                      console.log('Increase registrant succeeded: ' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
                   }  // end else
    });  // end def anonymous fn & def updateItem stateme
  }  //  end for
}  //  end def fn updateTable
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <label>First Name
    <input type="text" name="fname" size="25">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last Name
    <input type="text" name="lname" size="25">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>email address
    <input type="email" name="email" size="25">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>08:30 Keynote Speaker
    <select class="select" name="select 0830">
      <option value="unsure">unsure</option>
      <option value="attend">attend</option>
      <option value="not attend">not attend</option>
    </select>
  </label>
    <label>09:00 Classes
    <select class="select" name="select 0900">
      <option value="unsure">unsure</option>
      <option value="A">room A</option>
      <option value="B">room B</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <label>10:30 Classes
    <select class="select" name="select 1030">
      <option value="unsure">unsure</option>
      <option value="A">room A</option>
      <option value="B">room B</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit form">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I would guess that, even if you removed your custom javascript, that you would continue to see the behavior you mentioned. Have you tested without your custom JS and determined whether you get the same or different results?

Comment: @Brandon I have. I did before posting here. I should have said. With the custom JS commented out, the form connects with MailChimp correctly. With the script in place, it will not, although it does connect to an email address if I choose that option. And, of course, it did connect to MailChimp twice out of the first 5 tries but not since.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for all the trouble you went to. It was something on Mailchimp's end -- a new feature I didn't know about that I was butting up against. They changed the way they handle deleted list subscribers. Once deleted, no subsequent attempted submission will get through. And I had deleted myself, so subsequent trys from my email address were refused -- without notice or message. I finally got through to Mailchimp tech support and they told me what was happening. Thanks again for your interest and time. I'm really very grateful.

Comment: I had suspected it was not due to your JS. I also had observed that deleted users would not be re-added. However, in such cases, an email with the "There was an issue..." should not be generated...the user should simply NOT be added, silently. I suspect you were indeed running into a mix of related-but-separate issues and it happen to align with your code updates. I'll update my answer, because I think this question will get searched-for in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. Very kind of you. I hope it does help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this error message is often the result of either:

1. Fields required by MailChimp were not filled in on the form (double check you are requiring and filling in fields consistently during your tests), or
2. The person (email address) is already in the MailChimp list.
3. The email address was previously on the list, but was deleted. MailChimp will not re-add deleted users.

Assuming that it is not your custom javascript, and that you'll get the same results with or without your custom JS added, check both of those two possible causes.

Comment: Brandon: Thanks for taking an interest. The only field at MailChimp marked required is the email address and over that, I have no control. All the required fields on the Squarespace side are filled in.

I get a positive result without the custom JS. Only with it does the submit fail to connect to MailChimp. I have half a dozen email addresses to use, so I don't duplicate on the tests. However, I've checked and if the email address already exists in the list, MailChimp simply replaces the values in the list with the values in the new submission.

Comment: It didn't occur to me in my first comment, but you mention "this error message." Part of my problem is that there are no error messages. The code functions correctly without error. The console log shows confirmatory messages from AWS that the table update was successful. The script terminates correctly without error. The failure to connect to MailChimp generates no error message. I get.an email from Squarespace notifying me that there was a connection failure but without an error message other than that. That's part of my frustration.

Comment: One further message, Brandon. In addition to successfully connecting to an email address, it also connects to a Google Drive spreadsheet. Only the MailChimp account seems to be the problem. I have a tech support request in to MailChimp.